# Multivariate extensions of Ledoux--Talagrand contraction principle

Tags: pr.probability, contraction-mapping

Let $\{\varepsilon_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a sequence of independent Radecmacher (i.e., symmetric Bernoulli) variables, and let $\phi_i :\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be contraction (i.e., 1-Lipschitz) mappings that vanish at zero ($\phi_i(0) = 0$). Finally, let $F :[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ be a nonnegative, nondecreasing  convex function. Then,
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb E F \Big( \frac12 \sup_{t \in T} \Big|\sum_{i=1}^n \varepsilon_i \phi_i(t_i) \Big|\Big) \le     \mathbb E F \Big(  \Big|\sup_{t \in T} \sum_{i=1}^n \varepsilon_i t_i \Big|\Big)
\end{align*}
where $t = (t_1,\dots,t_n)$ and $T$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb R^n$. This result is known as the Ledoux--Talagrand contraction principle. First (minor) question:

> Is the "vanishing at zero assumption" necessary? I have seen results without this assumption
> for the case where $F$ is the identity map. Can we drop it for general $F$?

The main question is about the extension of this result to the multivariate case where each $\phi_i$ is mapping $\mathbb R^d$ to $\mathbb R$,  $t_i \in T_i \subset \mathbb R^d$ and $T = \prod_i T_i$. We let $t_{ik}, k= 1,\dots,d$ denote the coordinates of $t_i$.
I can find two extensions to this setting in the literature:

1. A result of [A. Maurer](http://www.andreas-maurer.eu/ContractionALT2016.pdf) that gives
   \begin{align*}
       \mathbb E \sup_{t \in T} \sum_{i=1}^n \varepsilon_i \phi_i(t_i)  \le 
       \sqrt 2 \mathbb E \sup_{t \in T} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^d \varepsilon_{ik} t_{ik} 
   \end{align*}
   where $\{\varepsilon_{ik}\}_{i,k}$ is an independent Radecmacher sequence and $\phi_i: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ are assumed to be contractions  w.r.t. the $\ell_2$ norm on the input space.
2. A result of [S. van der Geer](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-319-32774-7_16.pdf) that gives
   \begin{align*}
       \mathbb E \sup_{t \in T} \Big|\sum_{i=1}^n \varepsilon_i \big(\phi_i(t_i) - \phi_i(t^*)\big)\Big|  \le 
        C  2^{d-1} \mathbb E \sup_{t \in T} \Big|\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^d g_{ik} (t_{ik} - t^*_k)  \Big|
   \end{align*}
   where $\{g_{i,k}\}_{i,k}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ variables, $t^* \in T$ and  $\phi_i: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ are assumed to be contractions  w.r.t. the $\ell_1$ norm on the input space.

Both of these results are extension of the "$F = $ identity case"  of the original result. My question:

> Are there similar extensions (hopefully with constants not
> exponentially dependent on $d$) for  the case of the general $F$ in
> the original result. In particular, $F(x) = e^{\lambda x}$ for
> $\lambda > 0$ is of interest for bounding moment-generating functions.

Comment: Vanishing at zero is necessary. Consider $T=\{0\}$, $\phi_j(t)=2N$. The inequality becomes $E F(N|\sum \varepsilon_j|)\leq F(0)$ this cannot hold for all constants $N$ unless $F$ is constant.

Comment: @PaataIvanishvili, OK, thanks. I guess if there is no absolute value around the "sup" on both sides and F is the identity map, then vanishing at zero can be removed (?)